# Alternative ways to create a repetitive vector in R

Tags: r

I am tasked to create the vector

`0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1`

using **two** approaches ***without*** using `c()` or `rep()` in R.

I have tried a bunch of methods, but none of them seem to work.

Here are some of my attempts (all of which have failed) -

```
vector(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)


a<-seq(from = 0, to = 1 , by = 1)
a
replicate(5, a)


b<-1*(0:1)
do.call(cbind, replicate(5, b, simplify=FALSE))
```

Any help on this would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you use a loop?

Comment: What about `0:9 %% 2`?

Comment: yes, loops can be used. And @Greg, that seems a good solution, except it gives an `unexpected input` error

Comment: @user1993 Did you copy it verbatim?

Comment: oh sorry, I initially only had the one `%`. This works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @user1993 I [just added](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69229779/7) a generalized solution `my_rep()` for you, which can replicate any vector `x`, `n` times; and which uses neither `c()` nor `rep()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `bitwAnd`

```
> bitwAnd(0:9, 1)
 [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

or `kronecker`

```
> kronecker(as.vector(matrix(1, 5)), 0:1)
 [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

> kronecker((1:5)^0, 0:1)
 [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

or `outer`

```
> as.vector(outer(0:1, (1:5)^0))
 [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: Nice option with biwAnd

Comment: @akrun Thanks for your appreciation :)

Comment: Foul! You used `c()` :)

Comment: @Adam Good points! Now they are fixed.

Answer (score 5):

## Solution 1: Generalized Function `my_rep()`

A generalized solution `my_rep()` for any vector `x` you wish repeated `n` times

```
my_rep <- function(x, n) {
  return(
    # Use modulo '%%' to subscript the original vector (whose length I'll call "m"), by
    # cycling 'n' times through its indices.
    x[0:(length(x) * n - 1) %% length(x) + 1]
      #  1  2  ...  m   1  2  ...  m       1  2  ...  m 
      # | 1st cycle  | | 2nd cycle  | ... | nth cycle  |
  )
}
```

which can solve this case

```
my_rep(x = 0:1, n = 5)
#  [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

and many others

```
# Getting cute, to make a vector of strings without using 'c()'.
str_vec <- strsplit("a b  ", split = " ")[[1]]
str_vec
# [1] "a" "b" ""

my_rep(x = str_vec, n = 3)
# [1] "a" "b" ""  "a" "b" ""  "a" "b" ""
```

## Solution 2: Binary Vector of Arbitrary Length

Another quick solution, for a `0 1 0 1 ... 0 1` vector of arbitrary length `l`

```
# Whatever length you desire.
l <- 10

# Generate a vector of alternating 0s and 1s, of length 'l'.
(1:l - 1) %% 2
```

which yields the output:

```
[1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

## Note

Special thanks to [@Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10917479), who figured out `0:9 %% 2` on their own, shortly *after* [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/122361438) with that same solution; and who gracefully retracted their initial answer in favor of mine. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way using the apply functions.

```r
unlist(lapply(1:5, function(x) 0:1))
# [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Similar but with replicate.

```r
as.vector(replicate(5, 0:1))
# [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

And just in case you love trig.

```r
abs(as.integer(cos((1:10 * pi) / 2)))
# [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

And here is one last one that I consider cheating just because. This one generalizes to any vector you want!

```r
unlist(unname(read.table(textConnection("0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1"))))
```

Comment: Love the trig approach!  Mathematical cyclicality is fun to leverage.  :)

Comment: The trig approach is so innovative!!

Comment: I needed to redeem myself after copying like 3 ideas first!

Comment: The last one could be greatly simplified to `scan(text="0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1")`

Comment: @IRTFM yes very true. The more you stare at problems like this the more you miss the simple ones!

Answer (score 3):

Exploiting boolean coercion.

```
+(1:10*c(-1, 1) > 0)
# [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Or without `c()`.

```
+(1:10*(0:1*2) - 1 > 0)
# [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: wow, I have no idea how this works, but it sure does!

Comment: @user1993 The `c(-1, 1)` gets recycled in the multiplication with `1:10`.

Comment: Also uses `c()`. I kept struggling to find a way around using that for things like that! You can replace `c(-1, 1)` with `(0:1 * 2) - 1` though.

Comment: interesting. And what is the `>` and `+` for?

Comment: @Adam Thanks for deferring my to answer!  It was very sportsmanlike of you, and I've included an acknowledgement in [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69229779).  :)

Comment: @user1993 The `>` operator is a "greater than" comparison.  The idea is that `1:10` gives you `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`, which is then multiplied by `c(-1, 1)` to get `-1  2 -3  4 -5  6 -7  8 -9 10`.  Since these alternate negatives and positives, the comparison `> 0` is a test for positive numbers that yields the logical vector `FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE`.  And since the logical `FALSE` is coerced to the numeric `0`, and the logical `TRUE` is coerced to the numeric `1`, then boolean coercion results in the numeric vector `0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1`.

Comment: @user1993 Try to decompose the code into its units of meaning, the `> 0` compares whether the multiplication is greater than zero which yields boolean, and the `+` coerces to numeric.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Greg for the elaborate explanation! Thanks to jay too

Answer (score 3):

We can use `purrr::accumulate`, and a simple negate(`!`) operation.
`accumulate` will perform the same operation recursively over its data argument and output all intermediate results.
In this case, it can be broken down into:

```
output[1] <-0
output[2] <-!output[1]
output[3] <-!output[2]
...
```

the output would then be `c(0, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)`, which is coerced to numeric.

```
purrr::accumulate(0:9, ~!.x)

[1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: This is interesting, upvoted! By the way, could you give a short explanation? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, ThomasIsCoding. I included an explanation, as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly we will make a list of given no. and then apply `unlist()` function on list to *convert it into a vector* as shown in below code:

```
my_list = list(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
v = unlist(my_list)
print(v)
[ 1 ] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```